# 403 Permission Denied error when using Client_Secret.JSON file to connect to google spreadsheet API

Tags: google-drive-api

I was able to use the client_secret.json follow to query a googlespread sheet in my application using the google spreadsheets API.

However, someone else using my application gets a 403 permission denied error.

Using the developer console, I can create a new user for the project, but this just returns the client_secret.json file I already have.

How do I give permission to the user?

```
    INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
    ERROR:kernel_admin.__main__:{
      "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Google Sheets API has not been used in project     
626378963637 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sheets.googleapis.com/overview?project=626378963637 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "Google developers console API activation",
            "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sheets.googleapis.com/overview?project=626378963637"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you enable Sheets API at API console? If you had already done this, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Go to you Google Dev Console and enable Sheets API first:

[image]

To create permissions for files in your drive (that includes Google Spreadsheets), use [Permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create).

Comment: Thanks. I was able to enable the API sheet, but when the user of my CLI goes to this page, the they cannot click on 'enable' tab. Does the user need to go to this page, or do they need a different client_secret.json file?

Comment: this page is only for u, the creator of the app,  not for your users.

Comment: Okay, how do I allow a user to use the app?